# Undo searchBar background Image for one screen iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am working on a page which contains searchBar. So I used `UISearchController` for it.

In app delegate we have changed the appearance of `UISearchBar` by adding image to the background.

```
UISearchBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "search-bg"), for: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Now when I am using the searchController in a viewcontroller, on tapping searchBar there seems to be a black curtain view on the searchBar:

[image: search bar when tapped]

When I removed the `UISearchBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage`, searchBar seems to look fine. But I need that change in searchBar, so I tried changing the background image by setting:

```
self.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage.init()
```

But this too does not work.

Is there a way to undo the setBackground Image for one viewcontroller? Or any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let appearence =  UISearchBar.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([ViewController.classForCoder()])
appearence.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "search-bg"), forBarPosition: UIBarPosition.Any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```

Comment: this will allow me to initialize it with UIImage.init(), but will not undo the effect. How can i set no image.

Comment: Either set the custom bg image for desired view controllers or set the default bg image just for the view controller where you dont need the custome bg. Note: You will have to add default bg image to your resources, setting UIImage with no image reference will not help.